# How do I access a file path in Blazor?

Tags: c#, file, directory, webassembly

I added a file to

**wwwroot/assets**

the file is called **zip.csv**

```
private const string fileName = "zip.csv";
private const string filePath = "/assets/";
```

In my method,

```
var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath + fileName);
```

I am getting a crash (log below)

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/assets/zip.csv".
```

I can navigate to http://localhost:5000/assets/zip.csv and download the file

Comment: I'm not experienced in Blazor, but i don't think you can use System.IO to fetch a file remotely, since the namespace is used for local files, which you can't fetch in a browser. You should probably use Http.GetStreamAsync() or similar

Comment: Once I do this, how can I split the file? forEach(var line in response) if(line.Split(",").... the Split method doesn't exist.

Comment: Convert it to string first.

Answer (score 0):

Clientside Blazor is running in the same sandbox as javascript. To interact with the user's file system, use the HTML standard for accessing the file system, e.g. with this [Blazor wrapper](https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader).

Maybe localStorage is sufficient ? Check this [Blazor package](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage) to use it

Comment: There is also [this library](https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess) to bring up File Open and File Save dialogs from Blazor WebAssembly.